# Eclipse Error for GLPK library: The dynamic link library for GLPK for Java could not beloaded

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, glpk

I have a java program in which a use the GLPK Solver. The error that i receive when i run it on eclipse is the following:

```
The dynamic link library for GLPK for Java could not beloaded.
   Consider using
   java -Djava.library.path=
   The current value of system property java.library.path is:
   /Users/maria/Documents/solver_library/GLPK/w64
```

I had the same problem on my old windows computer and i solved it doing the following:
1. Adding in the Java Build Path->Libraries the glpk-java.jar file
2.Adding as the Native library location of the above jar the corresponding path (C:\ProgramFiles\solver_library\GLPK\w64
3. adding in the PATH environment variable the above path.

I am doing exactly the same things on my new MAC OS X computer but still receiving the above error. I did with exactly the same way the steps 1 and 2 above and also I modified through the terminal the PATH system variable. This now is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/maria/Documents/solver_library/GLPK/w64
```

Could you please tell me if you have any idea of how to solve this? I am a new Mac user so i don't know many things.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to make it work on OS X.

1. Install glpk.
   I used for this homebrew
   $ brew install glpk
   $ brew install swig // this package we well need for glpk for java
2. Install glpk for java http://sourceforge.net/projects/glpk-java/files/glpk-java/
   Unzip the archive with:
   $tar -xzf glpk-java-1.0.37.tar.gz
   $cd glpk-java-1.0.37
   Configure with:
   $./configure \
   CPPFLAGS=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers \
   SWIGFLAGS=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
   Make and install with:
   $make
   $make check
   $make install
3. Now in swig dir you should have 3 jars:
   glpk-java.jar, glpk-java-sources.jar, glpk-java-javadoc.jar and the .lib folder (hidden).
4. For compiling you need to put glpk-java.jar in your classpath and specify javac option -Djava.library.path=/YOUR_PATH/libglpk-java-1.0.37/swig/.libs